# Using was or were

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Which one should I use in a sentence such as this:

The abstract **or** the references **information** of many papers was/were not available.

Comment: The phrase should be "reference information" using the singular of reference.  Reference is modifying information.

Comment: No. It means that the information of the references of the paper.

Comment: Even though a paper may have more than one reference, it only has one reference section. So i still think that reference should be singular. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "information", like the nouns *news, money, advice,* etc., is uncountable and is used with verbs in the singular form no matter what modifiers are used with it.

If you use countable nouns, in the subject-verb agreement it doesn't matter what comes between the subject and the verb. The verb agrees *with the subject*, not with a noun or pronoun in the phrase.

> **One** *of the boxes* **is** open
>
> The **people** *who listen to that music* **are** few.
>
> The team **captain**, *as well as his players*, **is** anxious.

In this regard, don't let "of many papers" in your sentence mislead you.

Whether the "abstract information" or "references information" collocations are appropriate usage, is another question.

Comment: This does not apply to my question. In my question information refers to both "the abstract" or "the references". In other words it is a short form of "The abstract information or the references information of many papers was/were not available." In the case of this short form which one should be used?

Comment: @Shayan- I'm sorry, the answer's been re-written.